# Factory Class making db/service calls

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory

I need to refactor several long methods.

In our app, we make a series of documents, all of the same kind with different values obtained from values in the app. All of that code is now in a helper class, however, I want to use a factory class to produce the documents. The factory should behave such that, if `A` then call `factory.getDocument("A")` , if `B` then call `factory.getDocument("B")`.

My issue is that in order to construct the document I need values from my database, and I read somewhere (or someone advised me) that services should not be included in factory classes. If this is the case, how do I construct the full objects?

Is it acceptable to make service/db calls in my factory class?

If not, then should I pass arguments for the values I need to construct the object (e.g.  `factory.getDocument(a,b,c,d)` or an `inputobject`)? This seems to defeat the purpose of having a factory class, because the caller would require information about how to make document `A`, so I would prefer to avoid this approach. I want the calling method to know nothing about how the document is made.

What are my options?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem with accessing database from factory. Factory's purpose is to produce objects based on some input. So what if input is coming from database?

Comment: The main thing to be wary of is creating cycles in your object graph, like service -> factory -> service.

Answer (score 1):

I kind of disagree with the idea of using Factory pattern to create a same class and populate it with different data. Creating a Java class as per some criteria and populating it are different concerns and hence they shall be handled by separate entities.

Ideally Factory class is only responsible for instantiating the correct entity based on some type of user input. In your example I would say only use Factory class if you have different types of Document class implementations. Populating Document class shall be handled by separate entity (which can be singleton if required).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the question was edited, so I will change the answer.

Something in your code needs to know what is meant by document "A" and "B" if you want your caller to not know the parameters to create those.  There's no reason why that logic can't be contained in your factory, or at least the factory is responsible for looking up how to create "A" and "B" - that seems very sensible for a factory pattern.

Its still the case that I would put the access to the db via a singleton, even if that's just to get the connection.  See: [Java Singleton Pattern](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2003/jw-0425-designpatterns.html)

Comment: See also the much more recent [Singleton Antipattern](http://caines.ca/blog/programming/singletons-anti-pattern-or-worst-anti-pattern-ever/)

Comment: Meh - there are issues with the singleton, especially relating to the lifetime of the object and the resources it 'contains', disposing of singletons when terminating something can be a design issue.  However I strongly disagree with some of the arguments in this article - all time people write code to allow or restrict access/functionality - that's the whole premise of encapsulation.  Singletons have a place but you have to respect their lifecycle as much as any other type object.

Answer (score 0):

Seperations of concerns says that you should use an abstract factory pattern and choose the correct one based on the documenttype.